# Java - InternetAddress is not validating international emails in few languages

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, validation, email

I need to validate international email-ids having usernames and domain names in foreign characters. For that purpose, I'm using the `InternetAddress()` class from `javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress`. While this technique is working fine for some languages, for few languages it is not working.

I have written a small program to test if it can validate the email address or not:

```java
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

public class EmailTest {
    
    public static boolean isEmailValid(String emailId) throws AddressException {
        InternetAddress internetAddress = new InternetAddress(emailId);
        internetAddress.validate();
        return true;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] emailIds = {
                "jayesh平仮名@aio.com",
                "用户@例子.广告",
                "用户@例子.广告.net",
                "अजय@डाटा.भारत.in",
                "अजय@डाटा.भारत",
                "अजय@gmail.com",
                "квіточка@пошта.укр",
                "χρήστης@παράδειγμα.ελ",
                "Dörte@Sörensen.example.com",
                "коля@пример.рф",
                "иван.сергеев@пример.рф"
        };
        
        for(String s:emailIds){
            try{
                if(isEmailValid(s)){
                    System.out.println(s + " -> Valid");
                }
            }catch (AddressException e) {
                System.out.println(s + " -> InValid; Reason: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
jayesh平仮名@aio.com -> Valid
用户@例子.广告 -> Valid
用户@例子.广告.net -> Valid
अजय@डाटा.भारत.in -> InValid; Reason: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains illegal character in string ``अजय@डाटा.भारत.in''
अजय@डाटा.भारत -> InValid; Reason: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains illegal character in string ``अजय@डाटा.भारत''
अजय@gmail.com -> Valid
квіточка@пошта.укр -> Valid
χρήστης@παράδειγμα.ελ -> Valid
Dörte@Sörensen.example.com -> Valid
коля@пример.рф -> Valid
иван.сергеев@пример.рф -> Valid
```

As you can see `用户@例子.广告` is shown as valid, whereas `अजय@डाटा.भारत` is shown as an invalid email address.

What could be the reason behind such behavior? Is there a way to solve this issue, so that it can validate for all languages?

Comment: Why do you actually want to validate this? The only way to ***really*** verify a email address is by sending a confirmation email and wait for an interaction with a link in the email.

Comment: Missing @ followed by domain.

Comment: @JoopEggen there actually is an @ in it, it is just very hard to spot :D

Comment: Sorry now I see; laptop screen.

Comment: How is this Question specific to Spring Boot?

Comment: @luk2302 Your first comment asking “why” is not helpful, and is rather unwise. It always make sense to sanitize your data, where possible, before using it. Sending emails with obviously invalid addresses is a waste of resources and time.

Comment: @BasilBourque wasting developer time on the endless task of verifying email addresses is worse than attempting to send an invalid email. You will be able to send a >100 million emails until the cost of hours of developer work is amortized. And you run the very real risk of blocking absolutely valid addresses anyway. Sanitizing user input: yes, santizing email addresses: no.

Answer (score 2):

If one adds a dump of the letters, and checks the domain name:

```
    for (String s : emailIds) {
        try {
            if (isEmailValid(s)) {
                System.out.println(s + " -> Valid");
            }
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            System.out.println(s + " -> InValid; Reason: " + e);
            s.codePoints().forEach(cp -> System.out.printf(
                    "- %s : %s, #%x, alpha %s%n",
                    new String(Character.toChars(cp)), Character.getName(cp),
                    Character.getType(cp), Character.isAlphabetic(cp)));
        }
    }
```

- **अजय@डाटा.भारत** -> InValid; Reason: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains illegal character in string ``अजय@डाटा.भारत''
- अ : DEVANAGARI LETTER A, #5, alpha true
- ज : DEVANAGARI LETTER JA, #5, alpha true
- य : DEVANAGARI LETTER YA, #5, alpha true
- @ : COMMERCIAL AT, #18, alpha false
- ड : DEVANAGARI LETTER DDA, #5, alpha true
- ा : *DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN* AA, #8, alpha true
- ट : DEVANAGARI LETTER TTA, #5, alpha true
- ा : *DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN* AA, #8, alpha true
- . : FULL STOP, #18, alpha false
- भ : DEVANAGARI LETTER BHA, #5, alpha true
- ा : DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AA, #8, alpha true
- र : DEVANAGARI LETTER RA, #5, alpha true
- त : DEVANAGARI LETTER TA, #5, alpha true

If one would remove the vowel sign, the email address is accepted.

```
        s = s.replace(" ा", "");
```

I tried to no avail a Unicode normalisation (combining devangari vowel signs), which works for *combining diacritical marks*, using the `java.text.Normalizer`.

```
s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKC);
```

As I am unfamiliar with Devangari script, you might research yourself.

Comment: FYI, this Wikipedia page talks about that letter `DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AA`: [Ā (Indic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ā_(Indic)). Not that I know anything about Indic scripts.